# How to parse JSON string with extra double quotes in python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I need to parse a badly formatted JSON String in python.

Here is an example

> "{""key1"":""value1"",""key2"":{""subkey1"":null,""subkey2"":{""subsubkey1"":9,""subsubkey2"":null,""subsubkey3"":null},""subkey3"":""strval1""},""key3"":""strval2"",""key4"":29}"

I've tried using `json.loads` and `pandas.read_json` to no avail. I have no control over creating the string - just need to parse it into a pandas DataFrame.

Comment: That isn't a valid json.

Comment: +1 to that. Any idea how I can get it into a valid format? Interestingly the file's original extension is CSV despite this looking closer to JSON. I just need to put it in a DataFrame at the end of the day

Comment: @mrdatascience32 Can you edit your question and put there the content of CSV (with headers etc.)?

Comment: @AndrejKesely there are no headers per say - the string in the question represents the full contents of the file with a .csv extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file contains this string:

```
"{""key1"":""value1"",""key2"":{""subkey1"":null,""subkey2"":{""subsubkey1"":9,""subsubkey2"":null,""subsubkey3"":null},""subkey3"":""strval1""},""key3"":""strval2"",""key4"":29}"
```

then you can do for example:

```py
import json

df = pd.read_csv("your_file.csv", header=None)
df_out = df[0].apply(json.loads)

# use read_json, or .apply(pd.Series) to convert the json to dataframe
df_out = pd.read_json(df.iloc[0, 0])
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
           key1                                                       key2     key3  key4
subkey1  value1                                                       None  strval2    29
subkey2  value1  {'subsubkey1': 9, 'subsubkey2': None, 'subsubkey3': None}  strval2    29
subkey3  value1                                                    strval1  strval2    29
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without `pandas` if you need to. Just you can replace doubled up quotes `""` with a single double quote `"`:

```py
import json

j = '''
{""key1"":""value1"",""key2"":{""subkey1"":null,""subkey2"":{""subsubkey1"":9,""subsubkey2"":null,""subsubkey3"":null},""subkey3"":""strval1""},""key3"":""strval2"",""key4"":29}
'''

print(json.loads(j.replace('""', '"')))
```